# League of Legends Terminology

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do those abbreviations mean in LoL?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol)

LoL uses a bunch of terminology. I can't find definitions for (and would like to understand the meaning of):

- Bruiser
- Jungler
- Carry (vs. Bruiser as well)
- Tank (high HP, low attack?)
- AP
- AD
- DPS (Damage per Second)?

It seems like bruiser/carry/dps refer to different types of offensive champions, while support is healing/helping champions, and tank is a defensive (high HP, low offensive) champ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do those abbreviations mean in LoL?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/what-do-those-abbreviations-mean-in-lol) and also related: [What is the difference between a “carry” and a “fighter”?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40630/what-is-the-difference-between-a-carry-and-a-fighter)

Comment: @FAE looked at them; helped but didn't answer my question about champion labels (specifically).

Comment: @ashes999 The labels LoL uses are for general game play, don't be surprised when you see some characters played as carrys who are usually tanks (Shen, Alistar, Singed, Blitzcrank, Galio, +more are fairly common.)   Instead of focusing on how LoL says to play them, look at guides or videos of gameplay and strats for characters you're interested in.  Mobafire.com is a decent place to start out to learn the basics of game play, strategy, and how to play your role.  http://solomid.net/  is really good once you understand the game and are looking to perfect your game play.

Comment: @Dave I'm purely asking about terminology, nothing more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Tank** = characters that can wade into battle and take vast amounts of damage. They also tend to have a lot of CC (Crowd-control) abilities, such as stuns, snares, taunts, silences, slows.
- **Jungle** = characters that roam through both jungles killing minions (including the large minions that grant red buff and blue buff) and ganking (ambushing) opponents. Usually  characters with good heal, attack, and speed, etc.
- **Carry** = they are the high-DPS champions. Usually squishier and needs to be protected by Tanks, etc. But let a Carry get away and game over. They do serious AP (Ability Power) or AD (Attack Damage).
- **SUPPORT** = Champion that supports his/her allies. Provides good map control, crowd control, and heals.
- **AP** = Ability Power aka Magic power. You need high MR (Magic Resistance) to counter
- **AD** = Attack Damage aka Physical power. You need high Armor to counter
- **DPS** = Damage Per Second. General benchmark on how much damage you are dishing out. Typically the more the merrier!
- **ATS** = Attack Speed - How fast a champion attacks (example = 1.00 ATS = 1 Attack per Second) Max 2.50.
- **MS** = Move Speed - How fast a champion moves.
  Good luck and have fun! LoL is awesome.
- **CV** = Clairvoyance - Summoner spell that reveals any area of the map.
- **CS** = Creep Score - The number of creeps a champion has killed.
- **OOM** = Out Of Mana - The champion saying this has no mana.
- **MIA or SS** = Missing in Action - Enemy in another lane is missing, so you should be cautious of a gank.
- **RE** = Return - Enemy who has been missing in action is back in the lane.
- **B** = Recall - Pressing the B Button to teleport back to base after 8 seconds.

Comment: There are a lot more terms than that; I'll see if I can think of some and add it in.

Comment: Oops, my bad I didn't read that he was only looking for specific definitions. Maybe just leave it in there for future reference?

Comment: Wouldn't it be AS not ATS? And EU servers use SS not MIA

Comment: @Jacxel - Thanks for the formatting. I still stink at doing that on the exchange sites. :)

Comment: @Valien I didn't change very much as regards formatting >.> you can check the edit history if you click the time above my name where it says I edited. I just added ss and oom and moved things around